# How do I properly implement completions with kthreads?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am attempting to write a kernel module that implements completions on kthreads.

The logic I am trying to code is: parent `foo()` will create a kthread `bar()`. `foo()` will call `wait_for_completion()` and wait for the thread `bar()` to finish. `bar()` will execute its body and then call `complete()` right before `return()`. Parent `foo()` continue the rest of its code to completion.

Here is an extract of the code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/completion.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <net/tcp.h>

//A couple of standard descriptions
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

//Struct used to pass kthread args
typedef struct {
    int side;       //Specify motor side
    int direction;      //Specify motor rotation direction
    struct completion wait_for_motor;   //completion struct
} kthread_arg;

//kthread struct declaration
static struct task_struct *left_motor;

static int motor_rotate(void* data) {
    //Cast and dereference argument structure
    kthread_arg in = *(kthread_arg*)data;

    int i = in.side;
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: motor side=%d\n",i);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: Completing kthread...\n");

    //Signal completion
    complete(&(in.wait_for_motor));

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: Kthread Completed.\n"); 

    return 0;
}

//Init function
static int main_init(void)
{
    /*  Body of code */

    //Initialize argument structures;
    static kthread_arg kta_left_motor;

    //Set motor side
    kta_left_motor.side = 0;

    //Initialize completion
    init_completion(&kta_left_motor.wait_for_motor);

    //Create and run kthread
    left_motor = kthread_run(&motor_rotate, (void*)&kta_left_motor, "motor_rotate_0");

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: Wait_for_completion...\n");

    //Put function to sleep until kthread signals completion
    wait_for_completion(&(kta_left_motor.wait_for_motor));

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: Completion done.\n");

    /*  More function calls and code    */

    return 0;
}

//Exit function
static void leave_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exit module.\n");
}

module_init(main_init);
module_exit(leave_exit);
```

Here is the `kern.log` output:

```
Module: Wait_for_completion...
Module: motor side=0
Module: Completing kthread...
Module Kthread Completed.
```

Notice that the the parent function is never awakened and we never get to the line `printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module: Completion done.\n");`. When I run this code the module simply hangs.

I have read the [completions document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/completion.txt) top to bottom about 100 times, I have attempted using `complete_all()`, checking the value of `done` (always outputs 0), using `completion_done()` and `try_wait_for_completion()` to no success.

I don't know if there is a better way to go about achieving the goal explained above.

If I remove the completions implementation entirely I find that the parent function `foo()` is always executed to completion **before** all kthreads start running, whereas what I need is for `foo()` to run only **after** *all* kthreads are done executing.

Ubuntu

`uname -r: 4.10.0-42-generic`

Comment: try use `wait_for_completion_interruptible_timeout` (and also without timeout): if not, the process can be unkillable

Comment: @Leos313 check [Hercules dd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134544/8834890) answer. It was a simple misuse of structure pointer.

Comment: I know, I am not answering. I am just adding something useful that you can use! ;)

Comment: @Leos313 now I understand what you are suggesting. Very useful indeed as I no longer have to reboot my system every 5 minutes as my kernel keeps locking out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify `motor_rotate()` as shown below:

1. `kthread_arg *in = (kthread_arg *) data;`
2. `int i = in->side;`
3. `complete(&(in->wait_for_motor));`

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked! I believe the problem I was having with the original code is that I created a new structure and copied that contents of it into this new structure. I later attempted to modify the newly-created structure rather than the original (which the parent function is reading). With the change you made we are creating a pointer structure that points to the original structure. This way the modification complete() modifies the same value being read by the parent function.